# Problems with function involving strings in Swift/Watchkit

Tags: ios, swift, watchkit, apple-watch

I am very new to Swift and Watchkit, and am working on my first project.

My problem is that the Apple Watch app crashes whenever the function updateMessage() is run.  This function updates a score/risk label.

```
  var counter = 0
  var risk = 0


  func updateMessage() {

        if counter == 0 {
            risk = 1
        }

        if counter == 1 {
            risk = 1
        }

        if counter == 2 {
            risk = 9
        }

        if counter == 3 {
            risk = 22
        }

        if counter == 4 {
            risk = 22
        }

        if counter == 5 {
            risk = 22
        }



        var message = "Score \(counter) | Risk \(risk)%"
        curbLabel.setText(message)
    }
```

Comment: where does it crash? what is the error message?

Comment: what is the type of curbLabel? The only issue that I can see with the code above is the curbLabel.setText(message).

If curbLabel is a UILabel, you need to assign the message string to the label by:

curbLabel.text = message

Comment: You should consider using a switch counter there instead of 6 if conditions.

Answer (score 0):

If I clear the debug breakpoint, everything works great.

Thank you for your help.  I really like the switch counter idea.